# Error when trying to free a previous malloc

Tags: c

I am using a function that allocates a given number of bytes from the user and then I have another function that is supposed to free the memory that was allocated. The memory segment serves as a pool that contains *x* equally sized list nodes.

Initial function:

```
void create_mem(int mem_size, int num_n){
     number_of_nodes = num_n;
     mem_block = malloc(mem_size);
     header = mem_block;
}
```

The header file has number_of_nodes, header and mem_block as an int, list_node* and char* respectively.

I also have a list_node structure in the header file:

```
typedef struct list_node {
     list_node* next;
}list_node;
```

The delete function:

```
void delete_mem(){
     free(mem_block);
}
```

The list works and my code contains insert_nodes and delete_nodes that work fine, but whenever my main calls the delete_mem function my program crashes.

When I changed the delete_mem function to:

```
void delete_mem(){
     mem_block = NULL;
     free(mem_block);
}
```

I get no errors, but I don't think this delete function actually does what I want it to do.

I believe I need to delete everything that is inside that original mem_block before trying to free the memory, but I am not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Not enough information. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Obviously, if you assign `mem_block = NULL` then the subsequent `free()` is equivalent to `free(NULL)`, which does nothing.

Comment: Best guess: somewhere (else) you are assigning a new value to `mem_block`, so that when you try to free it, its value is no longer the one received from `malloc()`.

Comment: Next guess: you attempt to free the memory more than once.

Answer (score 2):

You did it backwards. `NULL`ing the variable first means you leak the memory, then `free(NULL)`. `free(NULL)` is legal, but it's a no-op; it's too late to fix the leak since you lost track of the pointer. Use:

```
void delete_mem(){
     free(mem_block);
     mem_block = NULL;
}
```

to `free` first, then `NULL` out.

I don't know what might be in `mem_block`, but if it contains pointers to other allocated memory, you'd need to do a depth-first traversal of any pointer(s) it "owns", `free`ing the outer "leaves" before working your way back up the "limbs", so you don't `free` memory until all pointers stored in it have also been `free`-ed.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the variable mem_block's value not changed after malloc.

if it changed, the call of `free(mem_block);` will in trouble